# How do i reverse a CSS3 animation on the first iteration (and not the second)

Tags: javascript, animation, css, transition

I have setup a CSS3 animation like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

How do i reverse this animation on a class definition?

For example:

```
.slideinTransition {
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

This will reverse the animation on the second iteration, i would like to reverse it directly on the first iteration.

Comment: thanks for posting this question. didn't find how to avoid the creation of a slideOutTransition myself neither. I would be great if we could just add another class with something like "-webkit-animation:reverse" to trigger the animation in the other way...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
```

Comment: 2022 Update: webkit is no longer needed now, `animation-direction: alternate-reverse` will be just fine

Answer (score 10):

`-webkit-animation: slidein 2s ease-out -2s infinite alternate forwards;`

Just make the animation start at -[*duration*] sec to directly jump into the 2nd animation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are talking about, but surely flipping the from and to values would make it run backwards first time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is exactly what I want to avoid. On a more complex animation i would not want to rewrite the animation in reverse, but instead i would like to reverse the animation by a simple command in the class definition.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a better way to do this. I've read through http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Animations/Animations.html , and didn't see anything particularly helpful. Maybe file a webkit bug?